# How to list google account projects programmatically in Resource Manager v3?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api

**Intro:**

There is a [project.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) method in the Google [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager). One can simply perform:

```
GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects
```

with appropriate authentication and retrieve the list of projects associated with the account. Easy. Accounts belonging to an organization have appropriate `parent` set

```
  "parent": {
    "type": "organization",
    "id": "123456789012"
  }
```

accounts not being under any organization have just no `parent` node present at all.

There is also latest version of this API: [V3](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects). It **requires** the `parent` to be explicitly specified for the [project.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list) method (otherwise `403 Forbidden` with `PERMISSION_DENIED` is returned). This seems to be extremely inconvenient.

**Questions:**

- Is there any wildcard "root" value applicable here for the required `parent` (for V3)?
- If there is no wildcard and the caller is supposed to specify e.g. `organizations/123456789012`, what should be passed for non-organizational accounts?
- How could the non-organizational caller obtain his own "root" value? (Similar problems with the folders and [folders.search](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/folders/search) doesn't help).

**Note:**

Looks like the organizational account can use:

```
GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/organizations:search
```

To determine its own organization(s?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I was too fixed to the [project.list](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list) having the answer next to it... The [project.search](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/search) (with no extra parameters) is the desired project list:

```
GET https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v3/projects:search
```

Works for both account types.